# Is there a name for a multiplicative group with zero adjoined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For concreteness, say I take a groups of complex roots of unity and adjoin $0$ to it. What sort of thing have I got?

If I do this to two groups G and H, can't I take a group homomorphism $\phi : G\setminus 0 \to  H\setminus 0$ and make a homomorphism of these new objects by requiring that $\phi(0) = 0$? It seems to me this construction would generalise to other groups and ought to constitute a category.

If this works, what are these objects called and where can I read up on them? If it doesn't, what obvious thing have I failed to spot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object $G\cup 0$ is a semigroup (it is usually denoted $G^0$) and as **lhf** noted, it is not an interesting semigroup. Perhaps closest relatives of  $G^0$ are groupoids (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid) with joined $0$ and a new multiplication: $a*b=0$ if $ab$ is not defined in the groupoid. Moreover,  $G^0$ is just a groupoid with a single idempotent.

As to  homomorphisms, the requirement $\phi (0)=0$ is naturally for groupoids with $0$.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call them a group with zero adjoined. Another term for zero is [absorbing element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element). Not particularly interesting as an algebraic structure, though.

Comment: Thanks, "absorbing element" was a piece of terminology I was missing!